# Downloading a file in ubuntu from a website with wget

Tags: command-line, wget, download-manager

I am trying to download Hadoop from here: http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/www.apache.org/dist/hadoop/common/stable/
It contains the file *hadoop-2.9.2.tar.gz* which I am trying to access.
The command I am trying to use is along the lines of

```
wget  -P/home/ubuntu/Desktop/"http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/www.apache.org/dist/hadoop/common/stable/target=hadoop-2.9.2.tar.gz"
```

I know the target part at the end is the issue but I am unsure how to fix it.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command and link you are using seems to contain errors.  The actual format of `wget` is:

```
wget [option] [URL]
```

You removed spaces (which obviously matters) and added `target=` (which isn't there in actual URL). So, it must be something like:

```
wget -P /home/ubuntu/Desktop/ "http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/www.apache.org/dist/hadoop/common/stable/hadoop-2.9.2.tar.gz"
```

I have tested the above command and at my end it is working fine and successfully downloaded *hadoop-2.9.2.tar.gz* in the *Desktop* directory.

Comment: Thank you, and thanks for explaining the code also!

Answer (score 1):

I tested the following command, and it worked for me without any special options. (LANG=C to get output in English.)

```
$ LANG=C wget http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/www.apache.org/dist/hadoop/common/stable/hadoop-2.9.2.tar.gz
--2018-11-30 21:35:24--  http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/www.apache.org/dist/hadoop/common/stable/hadoop-2.9.2.tar.gz
Resolving ftp.heanet.ie (ftp.heanet.ie)... 193.1.193.64, 2001:770:18:aa40::c101:c140
Connecting to ftp.heanet.ie (ftp.heanet.ie)|193.1.193.64|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 366447449 (349M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: 'hadoop-2.9.2.tar.gz'

hadoop-2.9.2.tar.gz        100%[=====================================>] 349,47M  11,2MB/s    in 32s     

2018-11-30 21:35:56 (10,9 MB/s) - 'hadoop-2.9.2.tar.gz' saved [366447449/366447449]
```

The file will be stored in the current directory, so change directory to where you want the file before starting the command.